# не корректный вывод данных с++

Tags: c++, файловый-ввод-вывод

Возникла проблема с выводом данных в файле. Пожалуйста, напишите доступно и понятно, чтобы получилось исправить.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ofstream fout;
   ifstream fin;
   fout.open("lenghts.txt");
   if (!fout.is_open())
   {
       cout << "Could not open file lengts.txt"<< endl;
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "File lengts.txt was opened and ready to work" << endl;
       for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
       {  // условие для того чтобы не переводило строку в конце файла
           if (i == 15)
           {
               cout << "Enter first length of the rectangle N" << i << endl;
               int a;
               cin >> a;
               fout << a;
               fout << "\n";

               cout << "The second length of the rectangle N" << i << endl;
               int b;
               cin >> b;
               fout << b;
           }

           else
           {
               cout << "Enter first length of the rectangle N" << i << endl;
               int a;
               cin >> a;
               fout << a;
               fout << "\n";

               cout << "The second length of the rectangle N" << i << endl;
               int b;
               cin >> b;
               fout << b;
               fout << "\n";
           }
           
       }
   }
   
   fout.close();
   
   fout.open("information.txt");
   fin.open("lenghts.txt");

   int array[30];       // создаем массив под 30 элементов
   while (!fin.eof())   // заполняем массив с помощью цикла
   {
       int i = 0;
       fin >> array[i];
       i++;
   }
   
   fout << "Lenghts\t" << "Perimetr\t" << "Square" << endl; 

   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i+= 2)    // с помощью цикла находим похожие элементы
   {
       if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) 
       {
           fout << array[i] << "\t" << 4 * array[i] << "\t" << pow(array[i], 2) << endl; // производим действия над найденными элементами
       }
   }

   fout.close();
   fin.close();

   return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема кроется в цикле:

```
 while (!fin.eof())   // заполняем массив с помощью цикла
  {
      int i = 0;
      fin >> array[i];
      i++;
  }
```

Вы при каждом проходе цикла создаете переменную `i` заново и инициализируете ее нулем. Поэтому каждое следующее число считывается всегда в нулевой элемент массива, а в остальных содержится мусор, который потом попадает в файл.
Для решения проблемы Вынесете объявление и инициализацию `i` перед циклом.

Comment: спасибо большое!